the question wasn't for me it was to see if you guys could get the answer now I've already done all the coding figured I'd test your smarts
/*
  gcc password_cracker.c  -l crypto -o password_cracker.o

  https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-tools/blob/master/decrypt.c
  http://blog.csdn.net/lonelyrains/article/details/50837654
  http://www.cnblogs.com/lvpei/archive/2011/02/18/1957804.html
  http://www.cnblogs.com/fuyunbiyi/p/3475602.html
*/

#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>


//================
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PAGESIZE 1024
#define PBKDF2_ITER 4000
#define DISABLE_HMAC
#define FILE_HEADER_SZ 16

#define TEST_ROUND 2
#define LARGEST_NUM (268435456-1)
#define TRUCK_SIZE 1000



//===================
char* infile ;
//const char* outfile = "decrypted_sqlite.db";
char* passfile ;

const char hex_array[] = "0123456789abcdef";
//===================

// 0x9955bbc
unsigned long pass_sn = 0x9955bbc-2000;

void increse_num(void);
int quit_flag = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{


    long pass_start;
    long pass_end;
    long x;

    infile = argv[1];
    passfile = argv[2];
    pass_start = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 0); //atoi(argv[1]);
    pass_end = strtol(argv[4], NULL, 0); //atoi(argv[2]);

    char pass[8]= {'0'}; /* two bytes of hex = 4 characters, plus NULL terminator */


    int i, csz, tmp_csz, key_sz, iv_sz, block_sz, hmac_sz, reserve_sz;
    FILE *infh;
    int read;
    unsigned char *inbuffer, *outbuffer, *salt, *out, *key, *iv;
    EVP_CIPHER *evp_cipher;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX * ectx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(); 

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    evp_cipher = (EVP_CIPHER *) EVP_get_cipherbyname("aes-256-cbc");

    key_sz = EVP_CIPHER_key_length(evp_cipher);
    key = malloc(key_sz);

    iv_sz = EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(evp_cipher);
    iv = malloc(iv_sz);

    hmac_sz = EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha1());
#ifdef DISABLE_HMAC
    hmac_sz = 0;
#endif
    block_sz = EVP_CIPHER_block_size(evp_cipher);

    reserve_sz = iv_sz + hmac_sz;
    reserve_sz = ((reserve_sz % block_sz) == 0) ? reserve_sz : ((reserve_sz / block_sz) + 1) * block_sz;

    inbuffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(PAGESIZE);
    outbuffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(PAGESIZE);
    salt = malloc(FILE_HEADER_SZ);

    infh = fopen(infile, "r");
    //outfh = fopen(outfile, "w");
    read = fread(inbuffer, 1, PAGESIZE, infh);  /* read the first page */
    fclose(infh);

    memcpy(salt, inbuffer, FILE_HEADER_SZ); /* first 16 bytes are the random database salt */


    //PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pass, strlen(pass), salt, FILE_HEADER_SZ, PBKDF2_ITER, key_sz, key);

    memset(outbuffer, 0, PAGESIZE);
    out = outbuffer;

    memcpy(iv, inbuffer + PAGESIZE - reserve_sz, iv_sz); /* last iv_sz bytes are the initialization vector */


    printf("Start from %07x to %07x.\n", pass_start, pass_end );


    clock_t start = clock();
    for (x=pass_start; x<=pass_end && x <= LARGEST_NUM; x++)
    {

        pass[0] = hex_array[((x & 0xF000000) >> 24)];
        pass[1] = hex_array[((x & 0x0F00000) >> 20)];
        pass[2] = hex_array[((x & 0x00F0000) >> 16)];
        pass[3] = hex_array[((x & 0x000F000) >> 12)];
        pass[4] = hex_array[((x & 0x0000F00) >> 8)];
        pass[5] = hex_array[((x & 0x00000F0) >> 4)];
        pass[6] = hex_array[((x & 0x000000F) >> 0)];

        PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pass, strlen(pass), salt, FILE_HEADER_SZ, PBKDF2_ITER, key_sz, key);
        out = outbuffer;
        EVP_CipherInit(ectx, evp_cipher, NULL, NULL, 0);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ectx, 0);
        EVP_CipherInit(ectx, NULL, key, iv, 0);
        EVP_CipherUpdate(ectx, out, &tmp_csz, inbuffer + FILE_HEADER_SZ, PAGESIZE - reserve_sz - FILE_HEADER_SZ);
        csz = tmp_csz;
        out += tmp_csz;
        EVP_CipherFinal(ectx, out, &tmp_csz);
        csz += tmp_csz;
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ectx);

        // WeChat 7.0 use different write/read version
        // [5] = 64; [6] = 32; [7] = 32; [56:(56+20)] = 0;
        if( outbuffer[5] == 0x40 
            && outbuffer[6] == 0x20 
            && outbuffer[7] == 0x20
            //&& outbuffer[56] == 0x00 
            //&& outbuffer[57] == 0x00
          )
        {
            quit_flag = 1;

            printf("OK\n");
            printf("Pass: %s\n", pass);
            FILE *passfh;

            passfh = fopen(passfile, "a");
            fwrite(pass, 1, strlen(pass), passfh);
            fwrite("\n", 1, strlen("\n"), passfh);
            fclose(passfh);

            printf("outbuffer:\n");
            int kk,kkk;
            for (kk=0; kk<10; kk++)
            {
                for (kkk=0; kkk<10; kkk++)
                {
                    printf("%02x ", outbuffer[kk*10 + kkk]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }

        }

    }

    clock_t end = clock();
    unsigned long millis = (end - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    if (millis==0)
        millis = 1;
    float speed = (pass_end+1-pass_start)*1000.0/(millis);

    printf("END from %07x to %07x. Speed: %f/s .\n", pass_start, pass_end, speed );


    free(inbuffer);
    free(outbuffer);
    free(key);
    free(salt);
    free(iv);


    return 0;
}


I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Linux/UNIX.

I don't see a specific question here, just an open ended question that should be answered by the original documentation.

@user10489 The question is in the title (when it should be in the body), and the body consists of source code interspersed with pasted URLs. The OP also didn't show effort to attempt to solve the issue from the question.

The title is a broad unfocused question which is ok for a title, but not likely to get a useful answer.  The body should include more focus including any error messages or difficulties in following the original documentation.  The body contains no explanation at all or any focus.

The body appears to be a copy of a source file with no code fencing, so isn't correctly rendered. The URLs are part of a file header comment. Agree the body contains no focus. Given this is about a "password cracker" I would be hesitant to offer an answer without confirmation that there is a legitimate use for the tool.
